# Formal concise definition of boundary of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can't find it in Rudin's book, can anyone help?

I don't like the definitions on the internet they're too wordy

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

boundary(S) $\;$ = $\;$ closure(S) [$\cap$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) closure(complement(S))

Comment: Same remark as other answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can define it as the intersection between the closure of $A$ and $A^c$. There are many other equivalent definitions too.

$$ \partial(A)=\bar{A}\cap\bar{A^c}$$

Comment: This is the definition I have encountered most frequently.

Comment: @copper.hat: Yes, me too. But you can also define it as $\partial(A)= \bar{A}-A^{\circ}$ where $\bar{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$ and $A^{\circ}$ denotes the interior of $A$. There is also another definition based on neighborhoods and points of the space. A point $p$ in the space is in $\partial(A)$ iff every neighborhood containing $p$ contains at least one point in $A$ and one point outside of $A$.

Comment: @some1 : $\:$ That1 is very wordy. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Which one? All of them are or only the third one? Actually I avoided the third definition because it's too wordy, but you can't deny that the third definition is also useful, because in a sense it allows us to talk about points of the space rather than sets and operators ($\bar{ }$ and $^{\circ}$) defined on them.

Comment: I meant the third one. $\;$

Answer (score 2):

In a topological space $X$ , the closure of a set $S\subset X$ is the intersection of all closed sets $C\supset S$, and the interior is the union of all open sets $U\subset S$.

The boundary of $S$ is then the difference $C\setminus U$.

Comment: The closure is the *intersection* of all closed sets such that $S\subset C$

Comment: @Antoine: Sorry, edited.